# Creating different navwalker navigations for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am re-building our Learning Management System using WordPress. We use bootstrap and navwalker for the upper (main) navigation. I'd like to have another upper (main) navigation when the student is logged in. How would I go about this? Woudl you recommend my developer creates a different PHP Header Request?

So, at the moment all templates have this function:

```
<?php get_header();
```

Woudl the sensible thing be to create all the templates that need a different navigation like this:

```
<?php get_header(logged-in-templates);
```

So, the 'logged-in-templates) pull in the different navwalker...

Hope that makes sense!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understood you want to display different nav menus if user is logged in and if the user is not logged in. In such case you can register additional nav menu location in functions.php:

```
register_nav_menus( array(
    'logged_in_menu' => esc_html__( 'Menu for logged in users', 'yourthemename' ),
) );
```

and then just check

```
if(is_user_logged_in()) {
wp_nav_menu( array( 'logged_in_menu' => 'yourthemename' ) ); 
} else {
wp_nav_menu( array( 'primary_menu' => 'yourthemename' ) ); 
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?